# Issue with 100 kHz astable multivibrator

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, oscillator, simulation

I am trying to design an astable multivibrator to deliver an output frequency of around 100kHz. My requirement is to effectively toggle between two inputs (say A and B). They can’t be on at the same time so I thought an astable multivibrator would be prudent.

I have succesfully verified a lower frequency design (first picture) and this works as I would expect.

The issue is on the second design where I aim for a higher frequency. I should be getting an ouptut of around 154 kHz:

- f = 1/T = 1/1.38RC
- f = 1/1.38 x 4.7x10^3 x 100 x10^-9
- f = ~154 kHz

However I get no output at all. Note that for the simulation I am probing on the top node of R13 and R14. I used 10k resistors as a test load but the actual load could have a lower resistance.

I suspect the issue could be to do with the transistors not fully conducting into saturation but I am not sure.

I would appreciate any help as I feel I have missed something obvious. This is my first time designing such a circuit so any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: For a practical circuit 100 ohms is unnecessarily low for the collector resistor with 4.7k for the base resistor. Normally a forced Hfe of 10-20 would be used. 1k for collector and 10k-22k for base would be more common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the problems you are facing is transistor saturation. Transistor saturation significantly slows down transistor switching. By adding 2 Schottky diodes, (i.e. Baker clamps) I was able to reduce the timing capacitors to 4 nF and still get good oscillation behavior.

[image: schematic]

[image]

A second problem is the symmetry of the circuit. The symmetry of the voltages and currents in the circuit needs to be broken for the oscillations to begin. In real circuits, components vary, and so the circuit is not *perfectly* symmetric. Another mechanism by which symmetry is often broken is natural noise in the circuit. In simulations, imprecision introduced by approximations and rounding may or may not break the symmetry. In the circuit below, I substituted a 2N3904 for *one* of the 2N2222s, and was able to get the circuit to oscillate in simulation with 1 nF timing capacitors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feU14t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Hi Math Keeps Me Busy, firstly thanks for taking the time to look into this. Between your answer and the help from GodJihyo below I managed to get the simulation working by using the suggested Schottky diodes and altering one of the transistors. It didn't occur to me that the saturation would slow the transistor enough for it to cause an issue. Out of interest why is a saturated transistor so markedly less responsive? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not positive that saturation _is_ a problem in your case. But some time ago, I experimented with trying to get similar multivibrators to run above 100 kHz, and I did see improvement when I added Schottky diodes as in my answer. The reason saturation can slow down a transistor is that saturation leaves a lot of carriers floating around in a transistor when you are trying to turn it off. In that sense it is much like the problem of reverse recovery time in a slow diode. It takes time to clear the device of these extra carriers.

Answer (score 3):

It needs a little kick to get started.

Try adding **startup** to your simulation command (start external supply voltages at 0V) and change one of the 4.7k resistors to 4.75k to unbalance it a little.

This is what happens when you simulate and all the parts are identical, the circuit is perfectly balanced so oscillation doesn't start. In a real world circuit noise and little differences in component values will probably be enough to get it going even if you used 4.7k for both resistors.

Edit: The diodes Math Keeps Me Busy suggested help. With those in the circuit I was able to get it to start in LTspice just by adding a 1 pF capacitor from one collector to ground which will affect the duty cycle a lot less than changing the resistor value,

Comment: Ah! So I initially thought this could have been an issue but discounted it since the first example worked. However, your answer has made a lot of sense and I think that is what could be happening. I suppose adding that additional capacitor alters the RC characteristic for that leg enough to start the oscillation or am I incorrect? Also by using the startup command I assume that tells LTSpice to 'raise' the simulation voltage so it can properly simulate the capacitors charging rather than starting the simulation with a fixed voltage? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @SimonPCB Correct. Although now that you mention it it's funny the lower frequency one worked. Ah well, LTspice is a harsh mistress.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that transistor saturation could be a part of the problem, but 100 kHz isn't all that fast for a 2N2222.

As an alternative solution for your task, what about a CMOS 555 circuit.  Your schematic indicates a 50/50 output duty cycle, and the LMC555 datasheet has a circuit specifically for this.  Figure 17, page 16.

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc555.pdf?ts=1690458313164&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLMC555%253FkeyMatch%253DLMC555%2526tisearch%253Dsearch-everything%2526usecase%253DGPN

Comment: Hi AnalogKid, that is a very helpful link that you have found. I initially discounted using a 555 timer due to the fact I needed two outputs effectively 180 degrees out of phase with a 50/50 duty cycle, however I will investigate this solution as I wasn't aware of such a simple implementation. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @SimonPCB Keep in mind that there are two outputs, one of them 2-quadrant sink/source (OUT) and the other is open-drain (DISCHARGE). So they aren't 100\% the same. But both can be useful there. It's also 50%. Nice. And probably brings more things under management than your discrete circuit. (Though the BJT version you have can be modified to greatly improve it, it may not be worth the trouble given that a CMOS 555 is okay with you.)